# How do I turn on and off a solenoid every x days using ESP32 and Blynk?

Tags: arduino, esp32, blynk

I am building a sprinkler system using blynk and ESP32 wifi module. I have 6 solenoids that activate sprinklers, and I am looking to have them fire every x days, changing every month. So far, I have come up with code that: fires a relay at a specific time, and/or fires a relay for a given amount of time when a button is pressed in Blynk.

Where I am looking to go with this is having 6 solenoids fire back-to-back every x days, with x changing by month. I don't really know how to format the syntax for the 'every x days' part. Any tips?

Comment: Possible duplicate [How do I fire a relay using an ESP32 every x days?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61978231/how-do-i-fire-a-relay-using-an-esp32-every-x-days)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to use Blynk, is to put [the generated Blynk sketch](https://examples.blynk.cc/?board=ESP32&shield=ESP32%20WiFi&example=GettingStarted%2FBlynkBlink) in the Arduino and set the widgets in Blynk App.

To make a time schedule, use the BlynkTimer and/or Eventor widgets. The Blynk cloud handles the schedule even if the application is not connected.